# Leaking geysers

Tags: bathroom

The geyser valve is leaking a lot of water that we had to close it with a stopper.  The second one also has water coming out of it enough to fill the tray. It seem there issues with the hot water too  only little flow from the faucet.  What could be the problem?

Comment: what is a `geyser valve`?

Comment: A geyser is a localized term for [water heat systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_heating). I suspect that it's not a geyser valve we're discussing, per se, but a valve that controls flow to a heat radiator.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It isn't clear what you're asking; would you add some details (e.g. a picture)? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Old Faithful, now that's a geyser.